# Pod exiting from Kubernetes causes spike in Pod memory usage

Tags: python, kubernetes

We have this `python` image running a Sanic server with a simple entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3.9", "entrypoint.py"]
```

All of our orchestration is managed by Kubernetes.

Whenever a pod is deleted, the pod exits with a spike in memory usage, alerting our Grafana dashboards

How can I debug this?

Comment: What kubernetes cluster version is used? Is it cloud (like GKE, AKS or EKS) or on-premise? Does it happen only to this specific `image` or to any other ones? Does it work normally in general? There was an old issue with OOM errors and memory leak

Comment: Does this container has any `preStop` hook? May be the handler there is consuming this extra memory.

Comment: @moonkotte Yes, in our dev builds (`docker run`) it runs normally

Comment: @Narain There is no `preStop` hook as far as I am aware

Comment: @SanketDG Does it happen only with this image?

Answer (score 0):

its probably because the python process is doing something on exit thats eating ram. As a work around you can change grafana to a average ram usage across a time range to smooth out that spike